# Signature pop-up describes dataclass as "The most base type"

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-coc

I'm using [coc-python](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python) for Python IDE-like features.

If I define a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) I would expect the signature pop-up to show me which fields an instance of this class expects.

Instead I get:

```
MyClass()
------------------
The most base type
```

Here is a screenshot which shows the coc-python output:

[image: signature pop-up showing "The most base type"]

By contrast, a normal class with an `__init__` method shows the expected signature:

[image: pop-up showing correct signature]

I've filed [a bug report](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/277) but I thought I'd reproduce it here in case anyone has a workaround.

---

### Minimum working example

```python
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Shape:
    radius: int
    sides: int
```